# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined when binding 2 functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to bind in a var into some functions so i can have access to it in an inner function.

```
function checkIfIsFilter(currentfilters, parentSearch) {
       for (var group of currentfilters) {
            if (_.find(group.filters, {"search": parentSearch})) {
               return group.parentSearch || group.name;
            }
       }
 };

function checkIfSubtopic(currentfilters, memo, value, key) {
   if (value.parentSearch) {
       value.subtopicOf = checkIfIsFilter(value.parentSearch).bind(null, currentfilters);
   }
   memo[key] = value
   return memo;

}

 console.log(_.reduce(currentfilters, checkIfSubtopic.bind(null, currentfilters), {}));
```

This seems to break the functions, specifically at the `value.subtopicOf =` part with the error message of Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined. I just want to bring `currentfilters` into the inner most function so i can reference it. This was working fine when I have it as a global variable ( can just just reference `currentfilters` directly inside of the `checkIfIsFilter` function), but I will not be able to have it like that in production.

I have a fiddle here I've been working in : https://jsfiddle.net/0fttkyey/79/

Unsure what I am doing correctly, would appreciate any input. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is this question missing an AJAX, jquery or other library tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets shorten that a bit

```
function checkIfIsFilter(currentfilters, parentSearch) {
    return group.parentSearch || group.name;
}

function checkIfSubtopic(currentfilters, memo, value, key) {
    value.subtopicOf = checkIfIsFilter(value.parentSearch).bind(null, currentfilters);
}

console.log(_.reduce(currentfilters, checkIfSubtopic.bind(null, currentfilters), {}));
```

Note that `checkIfIsFilter` doesn't return a function, and you're doing

```
checkIfIsFilter(value.parentSearch).bind();
```

You're calling `checkIfIsFilter`, which returns `group.parentSearch` (or `name`), and the return value is what you're trying to bind to?

Firstly, if you want to call the function with a `this` value and arguments, you can just use `call`, `apply` or in your case, just call it directly, as the `this` value doesn't seem to matter.

Secondly, it looks like you're trying to use a dynamic property name, which only works with bracket notation

```
function checkIfIsFilter(currentfilters, parentSearch) {
       for (var group of currentfilters) {
            if (_.find(group.filters, {"search": parentSearch})) {
               return group[parentSearch] || group.name;
            }
       }
 };

function checkIfSubtopic(currentfilters, memo, value, key) {
   if (value.parentSearch) {
       value.subtopicOf = checkIfIsFilter(value.parentSearch, currentfilters);
   }
   memo[key] = value
   return memo;

}

 console.log(_.reduce(currentfilters, checkIfSubtopic.bind(null, currentfilters), {}));
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/0fttkyey/80/)

Answer (score 0):

Using bind doesn't seem to be needed here because the thisArg isn't really being used. Lodash provides a different function called partial to do exactly what you're trying to do though called partial.

I changed the last line of your code to this:

```
console.log(_.reduce(currentfilters, _.partial(checkIfSubtopic, currentfilters)));
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yqt8y0hb/

Comment: I'd probably also follow adeneo's advice about your functions if I were you.